# Extend empty object to fill it on event emitted angularJS

Tags: javascript, angularjs, oop, object, emit

From my service, I emit the event with  `$rootScope.$emit`. Then in controller `$on` this event I store passed data in the array. At this point, I am able to display this values in `ng-repeat` directive.

On fire service function it stores two new values to my array in the controller. This solution was good and working but now I need to display it in many different places so I want to save it not an array but an array object. Unfortunately, it is problematic for me, I do not know how I can create empty array object in javascript so it could be extended on every emit.

The schema of empty array object would look like:

```
arrayObject = [
    {
        firstValue: value,
        secondValue: value
    }
];
```

And I would need to extend this with data in the controller on the event, for now, my code which is saving to simple array looks like this:

```
$rootScope.$on('colorChanged', function(event, data) {
  console.log('colorChanged event emitted');
  console.log(data);
  if(data) {
      vm.convertedColors.push(data);
  }
});
```

Data is the string passed from service.

When I fire functions from service it executes 2 methods and emit event twice one on finish first method with firstValue and second with secondValue after the second method obviously. It would be much nicer to work with if it would be an object array instead of the simple array.

Is it possible?

### EDIT

Although I pass to this `$on` fucntion for example this value `{colorInHEX: "#ff0000"}` and `{colorInHSL: "hsl(0, 1%, 0.5%)"}` I got an error

> TypeError: Cannot read property 'firstValue' of undefined

```
vm.convertedColors = [];

$rootScope.$on('colorChanged', function(event, data) {
    console.log('colorChanged event emitted');
    console.log('colors in others: (in controller)' + data);
    console.log(data);
        lastObj = vm.convertedColors[vm.convertedColors.length - 1];
        if (!lastObj.firstValue || !lastObj.secondValue) {
            vm.convertedColors[vm.convertedColors.length - 1] = Object.assign(lastObj, data);
        } else {
            vm.convertedColors.push({});  // Push a new empty object
        }
    }
});

$rootScope.$emit('colorChanged', {colorInHSL});
$rootScope.$emit('colorChanged', {colorInHEX});
```

### EDIT2

So now problem is that this is replacing instead of add new, I created plunker demonstrating issue. The data from service is hardcoded in this one, so the value is same whenever I click button but it still should create new one `<li>` just with same value.

Link to plunker: [link](https://plnkr.co/edit/yy5vLEwxpqTRRIq1X9vo?p=preview)

Comment: it is possible you can push anything to array, array of objects is perfectly normal, but be ready to use filter/map/reduce/find when you go with that. Just declare empty array arr=[] and then do arr.push(yourobject)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If ECMAScript6 is not a problem , you can use Object.assign to set values for firstValue and secondValue properties:

```
// In your controller:
vm.convertedColors = [{}];

$rootScope.$on('colorChanged', function(event, data) {
    if(data) {
        var lastObj = vm.convertedColors[vm.convertedColors.length - 1];
        if (!lastObj.colorInHSL || !lastObj.colorInHex) {
            vm.convertedColors[vm.convertedColors.length - 1] = Object.assign(lastObj, data);
        } else {
            vm.convertedColors.push(Object.assign({}, data));  // Push a new object
        }
        $timeout(function() {});     // Force a new $digest cycle so view is updated.
        console.log("Array: ", vm.convertedColors);
    }
});

// Emitting in your service:

var colorInHSL = 'hsl(' + 1 + ', ' + 100 + '%, ' + 100 + '%)';
$rootScope.$emit('colorChanged', {colorInHSL: colorInHSL});
setTimeout(function() {
    $rootScope.$emit('colorChanged', {colorInHex: "#ff0000"});  
}, 3000);  // Wait 3 seconds before emiting the second value (just to see how things works)
```

Comment: I edit my question because of little error I've got using your solution, please take a look.

Comment: Try to ititialize the array with an empty object in it:

vm.convertedColors = [ {} ];

Comment: And in the emit, it should be $rootScope.$emit('colorChanged', {colorInHSL: ""#ff0000""});

Comment: One more thing I had to do to make it working is add `var` before `lastObj` and now I think it is working correctly. You can edit this also, before without `var` it didn't work.

Comment: Damn something is still wrong, I mean it doesnt print out any error but it's not adding to object it's replacing I'm `ng-repeat`ing in view values `{{n.colorInHSL}}<br>{{n.colorInHEX}}` where n is `convertedColors` and they are not multipling when I emit new data they replace first firstValue and next secondValue...

Comment: The `vm.convertedColors.length` is always equal to 1. The `typeof vm.convertedColors` is object. `console.log('Length: ' + vm.convertedColors.length); console.log('Type: ' + typeof vm.convertedColors);`

Comment: I can hardly say that this still replace instead adding I dont understand why. I will try to provide a Plunker soon.

Comment: Ok, add a plunker

Comment: I added plunker in question, take a look at EDIT2.

Comment: Yes actually this code is finally working. But when I put function from service in object it stops working correctly again. Look this plunker is working fine: https://plnkr.co/edit/yFoLySj5BJk8A9uton7o?p=preview but this when I put function in service to object it stops working: https://plnkr.co/edit/tSnFrj8bKLB7QRH69CCJ?p=preview . What I'm doing wrong again?

Comment: because You have renamed property colorInHex to colorInHEX. 

You have to change the code to:

if (!lastObj.colorInHSL || !lastObj.colorInHEX)